# Redirect working inconsistently?

Tags: php, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have this if else script which on 1 instance should redirect, but doesnt, can anybody see why?

```
if($usersClass->checkTwitterUserExists(
    $_POST['twitterUser'])) {
    print "<br><p>in use.</p>";
}

else {
    #set_include_path("");
    require 'library/Zend/Oauth/Consumer.php';    
    $rs = mysql_query("update `produgg_users` set `twitterUser` =  
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['twitterUser'])."' where 
        `id` = '".$usersClass->userID()."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($config);

    // fetch a request token
    $token = $consumer->getRequestToken();
    // persist the token to storage
    $_SESSION['TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN'] = serialize($token);
    // redirect the user
    $consumer->redirect();
}
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Javascript so I'm retagging it to oauth and twitter-oauth

Comment: Does it ever get into the else block?

Comment: Yes it gets to the else then refreshes, sometimes the redirect works though, its strange

Comment: Maneesh, please verify on your own first that the problem actually exists. This means you can reproduce it. Can you reproduce the problem users reported to you?

Comment: The `Zend_Oauth_Consumer::redirect()` function uses the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] ? If that's the case, it's because that var isn't allways correctly set, from what I've seen.

Answer (score -1):

No closing `}` (brace) on your if-else conditional.

Comment: There is, just before the else. Also, this would cause a syntax error, and the code wouldn't run at all.

Comment: @Lumbendil No, after the else { `}?`

Comment: @Lumbendil I want you to move the "redirect" to the start of the `else {}` conditional, then I want you to incrementally move it to the next line, until you find the offending piece of code that's preventing the redirect. Feel free to skip lines that are obviously OK. Makes sense? As a result, you'll find out whether it's failing in require, or failing in the oauth portion, or where ever.

Comment: I havent been able to recreate the problem but people on my website are having this issue?

Comment: @FinalForm sorry, thought you said the if, didn't notice the missing `}` at the end of the code because since code arround here are snippets, I don't give that much importance.

Comment: @Maneesh Patel simple then, the issue is with $_POST['twitterUser']. Is this being validated somehow? Can you throw on a file logger to this variable to see what users are putting in. There needs to be a logger in place.

Comment: Thanks @finalform can i ask what you mean by file logger, or where I can learn to do this? Thanksyou

Comment: @Maneesh Patel Literally, log user inputs to a file fopen() and see what stupid things they're putting in. Just be prepared to see insanely stupid inputs. Add exceptions, and wrap some of those method / class calls in try{} catch(Exceptions){}. Basically, you will agree you need "more data" to properly fix this problem right. Makes sense? It's a 10 minute process, that'll help fix your code in the long run.

Comment: Brilliant, Thankyou @finalform, however the problem seems to have been resolved now, im wondering if twitter has api limits?

Comment: @Maneesh Patel You wouldn't know right? Because you're not logging.